# Create a sublist of a linked list without using standard library

Tags: java, linked-list, sublist

I'm trying to figure out how to create a sublist of a linked list without using the standard library for a practice exercise.

I have a solution coded but I'm not sure if this is working properly. I don't have any compile errors that are coming up but wanted a second opinion if there is a better way to do this or if corrections should be made.

LinkedList class basic instance variables

```
public class LinkedList<E> implements DynamicList<E> {

    LLNode<E> head;
    LLNode<E> tail;
    int llSize;



    LinkedList(){
        this.head = null;
        this.tail = null;
        this.llSize =0;
    }
```

get method addressing LinkedList index

```
@Override
    public E get(int index) {
        LLNode<E> current = this.head;
        while(current.nextPointer != null){
            if(index == current.getIndex()){
                return current.getObj();
            }else{
                current = current.nextPointer;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Node class

```
public class LLNode<E>{
    E obj;
    LLNode<E> previousPointer;
    LLNode<E> nextPointer;
    int index;

    public LLNode(E obj){
        this.obj = obj;
        this.index=0;
    }

    public E getObj() {
        return obj;
    }

    public LLNode<E> getPreviousPointer() {
        return previousPointer;
    }

    public LLNode<E> getNextPointer() {
        return nextPointer;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public void setIndex(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }
}
```

Sublist method

```
@Override
    public DynamicList<E> subList(int start, int stop) {
        DynamicList<E> newDynamicList = new LinkedList<>();
        for(int i = start; i<stop; i++){
            newDynamicList.add(get(i));
        }


        return newDynamicList;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure you want to keep the index in the node object? i would expect the index to be the nodes position in the list, and therefore tied to a position and not an element. also, given this code all indices will be 0 causing the subList to output empty lists only, unless each node is assigned indices manually from the calling method.

Comment: The problem with having the index in a node, is that you cannot reuse that node in another (sub) list: the same node would need to have two different indices (one for each list it is in). Another problem is the head & tail node in the sublist: the head should not have a previousPointer in the sublist, but unless that node is also head in the source list, it *should* have a previousPointer. Similar situation for the tail node. In short, you'll need to create *new* nodes for your sublist ... you cannot reuse the nodes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that about the index in the Node object. Thank makes sense why that will not work.

Comment: @Anton then index's are being updated with add's and addFirst and addLast methods with loops. I'm not sure how to associate an index/position value for each node that is created in the LinkedList without tieing it to its respective Node Object. If I had the Node index/position instance variable in the LinkedList class how would I have an individual unique index/position value for each Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm seeing, that is a double linked list. As is suggested in comments, avoid using an index as part of the node itself, the index is part of the List, because the list controls the way each node is traversed to perform any operation (add, remove, find, etc)

My suggestion (for sublist):

- Check if the sublist is within the size of your list (you can throw some exception or return some default data, it depends on your design)
- Move the index control to the list
- For getting the sublist, you might have something like get the start node of the sublist, and then, use the `nextPointer` to traverse through the next nodes. You can calculate the size of the sublist and use that to control when you have to stop

```java
public DynamicList<E> subList(int start, int stop) {
        DynamicList<E> newDynamicList = new LinkedList<>();

        //here, you can validate the subList conditions to work (size, boundaries, etc)
        //an exception may be thrown if parameters do not meet some criteria

        int subListSize = stop - start;

        LLNode<E> current = get(start);

        while(newDynamicList.size() < subListSize){
            //Consider cloning the node and add it to the sublist
            newDynamicList.add(current);
            current = current.nextPointer;
        }

        return newDynamicList;
    }
```

The main reason for not using the `get` method for retrieve each node is that `get` operation search for the node from the beginning each time you call it. It is better to get the start node and start traversing the nodes from there.

Don't forget that created Sublist will contain a reference to the original list nodes. I suggest to clone the elements for avoiding affect the original node

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure how to do the node cloning though. I'll see if I can find some documentation on it.